# If a property doesn't specify `column=` in the `hbm.xml`, what is the corresponding column's name in the table in the database?

Tags: java, hibernate

In a hibernate mapping `.xml` file:

```
<hibernate-mapping>

  <class name="Customer" table="CUSTOMERS1">
    <id name="ssn"> <generator class="assigned" /> </id>
    <property name="firstName" column="FIRST_NAME"/>
    <property name="lastName" column="LAST_NAME"/>
  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

`<id name="ssn"> <generator class="assigned" /> </id>` doesn't specify `column=`. What is the corresponding column's name in the table in the database?

The above comes from an example of Hibernate application. I want to test it on my laptop, so I am trying to create a table in a database before running the Hibernate application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify the `column` attribute, it defaults to the `name` property of `id` i.e. `ssn` in your case

```
<id
    name="propertyName"                                          
    type="typename"                                              
    column="column_name"                                         
    unsaved-value="null|any|none|undefined|id_value"             
    access="field|property|ClassName">                           
    node="element-name|@attribute-name|element/@attribute|."

    <generator class="generatorClass"/>
</id>
```

> - name (optional): the name of the identifier property.
> - type (optional): a name that indicates the Hibernate type.
> - column (optional - defaults to the property name): the name of the    primary key column.
> - unsaved-value (optional - defaults to a "sensible" value): an    identifier property value that indicates an instance is newly
>     instantiated (unsaved), distinguishing it from detached instances
>     that were saved or loaded in a previous session.
> - access (optional - defaults to property): the strategy Hibernate    should use for accessing the property value.

**Does it matter if I create a table with a column named SSN, instead of ssn?**

If you want to make your column case insensitive, you have to enclose the column-names in your mappings in backticks, e.g. `column="`SSN`"`, the backticks don't show here due to formatting though.

Source: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id

Comment: Thanks. Does it matter if I create a table with a column named `SSN`, instead of `ssn`?

Comment: Updated my answer with your question!